# when fread to struct, wrong output in c

Tags: c, file, fread

Actually code is Turkish, but ı translated some word for maybe it's can help you.

Struct:

```
    typedef struct
{
char name[100];
char surname[100];
char idNo[11];
char tel[11];
char address[200];
char email[100];
}personel;
```

Code:

```
void personelListele(){

FILE *pdosya;

personel personelBilgi;

pdosya = fopen("personel.txt","rb");
if(pdosya==NULL){
    printf("personel.txt dosyası açılamadı");
    exit(1);
}

int c;

while(c!=0)
{
    c = fread(&personelBilgi,sizeof(personel),1,pdosya);

    if(c!=0){

        printf("Name= %s\n",personelBilgi.name);
        printf("Surname= %s\n",personelBilgi.surname);
        printf("id = %s\n",personelBilgi.idNo);
        printf("Tel = %s\n",personelBilgi.tel);
        printf("Address = %s\n",personelBilgi.addres);
        printf("Email = %s\n",personelBilgi.email);


        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Name:Guven

Surname:Yildiz

id No:12312312312

Tel No:98798798798

Email:mail@mail.com

Address:somewhere
```

Output:

```
Name = Guven
Surname = Yildiz
id No = 1231231231298798798798mail@mail.com
Tel No = 98798798798mail@mail.com
Email = mail@mail.com
Address = somewhere
```

idNo output is mixed idno, telno and mail. İts same for telno. I dont know why it's happened. I tried to change places, but doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hint: `int c;

while(c!=0)` --> What is the value of `c` when `while(c)` first executes?

Comment: I don't think this is anything like the real code. fread() reads in BINARY, so if your input really had headers like "Name:" I'd expect those headers to be in your output.  If you are reading a text file (not binary), you should open the file as "r" and use fscanf or fgets/sscanf for parsing.

Comment: You forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That  *null-terminated* bit is to tell where the string ends. And of course it needs space in your arrays. So a string of X characters needs space for X + 1 elements to contain the terminator. If you don't have the terminator, then all function handling your string will go out of bounds, and you end up with [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @NetJohn "Name" and others just wrote to make your reading easier. Of course there is no name in input

Comment: Thanks for help, I try to open space for terminator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this input:

```
id No:12312312312
```

is 11 characters, you overflow

```
char idNo[11];
```

because you don't allow space for the terminating `'\0'` character added to the string.

In this case, you can tell that the overflow has occurred, because you print the variable as a c string, on a character array that is not null terminated. In this case the behavior is undefined, but since you've read the data into your `struct`, the `printf` call keeps reading in memory until it finds a `'\0'` which happens to be in the next character array of your struct. Hence, the recognizable number.